# Can't move Azure SQL Database from one resource group to another

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-powershell, azure-resource-manager

We were trying to move a database from one resource group to another resource group. Unfortunately, we  got the below error message while tried to move the database :

**Move-AzureRmResource : ResourceNotTopLevel : Identifier '' is not a top level
resource.
At line:1 char:1
+ Move-AzureRmResource -DestinationResourceGroupName  -ResourceId /subscrip ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Move-AzureRmResource], ErrorResponseMessageException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ResourceNotTopLevel,Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Cmdlets.Implementation.Move
   AzureResourceCommand**

Please see the below command which we used to move the database,

> $resource = Get-AzureRmResource -ResourceName Name -ResourceGroupName oldRG
>
> Move-AzureRmResource -DestinationResourceGroupName NewRG -ResourceId $resource.ResourceId

Could you please tell us how can move the database to another resource group?

Comment: Do you just need to move one resource, which is the database from one resource group to the other?  Do you expect an solution in PowerShell or C#?

Comment: Please go through this link, it will help you out (https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/resource-group-move-resources/)

Comment: @juvchan I have to move one database from one resource group to another.

Comment: @NeerajSharma I followed the same doc , and successfully moved other resources like webapp, cloud service, etc. I am facing issue with sql database only

Answer (score 4):

You need to move the **resource Ids** of both the **parent database server** and the **database** together to another resource group.

The error:  `ResourceNotTopLevel : Identifier '' is not a top level resource` already clearly stated that the resource Id of your database is not a top level resource. This actually implies that you need to move the top level resource in order to move the child resource.

In this case, your top level resource should be your database server.

The `-ResourceId` parameter of the `Move-AzureRmResource` actually takes in string array `<String[]>`

This [link](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/281804-azure-resource-manager/suggestions/8505544-fix-move-azureresource-resourcenottoplevel-error) also reports an issue which is similar to yours here.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

According to the command you have given in the question, you didn’t supply values to DestinationResourceGroupName and ResourceId parameters.
You should give these parameters respectively the name of the destination Resource Group and the Id of the resource you want to move.

Example:

```
PS C:\> $resource = Get-AzureRmResource -ResourceName ExampleApp -ResourceGroupName OldRG
PS C:\> Move-AzureRmResource -DestinationResourceGroupName NewRG -ResourceId $resource.ResourceId
```

Please see https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/resource-group-move-resources/ for more details.

As the Move-AzureRmResource cmdlet is quite new and is updated frequently, please be sure that you are using the last PowerShell version.

Comment: Thank you. I followed the same doc, and I updated the command in the question. I have successfully moved other resources like webapp, cloud service, and storage accounts using the same command.

Comment: @itzforu, does my answer help to resolve your issue?

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all for your reply.

Finally I got reply from Azure support Team. According the support team, It is not possible to move individual databases across resource groups, the entire server needs to be moved

I have sucessfully moved the servers to another resoruce grops.

Below are the commands which I used with powershell to move the SQL servers.

> $resource = Get-AzureRmResource -ResourceName {servername} -ResourceGroupName {oldRG}
>
> Move-AzureRmResource -DestinationResourceGroupName {newRG} -ResourceId $resource.ResourceId

Comment: Hi, this is basically same as the answer I provided. Would you accept it as answer?

Comment: I just looked at your answer, and I have upvoted it. It is the answer for this question. However, I don't have the privilege to mark it as answer.